# Can I change my payment account?

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

So I have to Google play store accounts. One has money on it one doesn't. Whenever I try to make an in-app purchase, it defaults and tries to make me pay with the account without any money. I have an ineffective PayPal account on the account with no money if that's the problem. Please help!

Comment: Also [see](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4646404?hl=en) this Google help

Answer (score 0):

I dont know is it possible in Your Country, but in my Country it is possible to bind Google Play billing account with billing account of my mobile operator that is Orange Poland. So any payments from Google are added to my monthly fee in Orange. So I remove PayPal from my Google profile.